# Why does the child class does not inherit the method from parent class in python in this example?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have the following code.

```
class Foo(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.__baz = 40
     def foo(self):
         print self.__baz

class Bar(Foo):
     def __init__(self):
         #super(Bar, self).__init__()
         self.__baz = 21
     def bar(self):
         print self.__baz

x = Bar()
x.foo()
x.bar()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classes.py", line 15, in <module>
    x.foo()
  File "classes.py", line 5, in foo
    print self.__baz
AttributeError: 'Bar' object has no attribute '_Foo__baz'
```

why is the `foo` method not inherited in `Bar`.

**EDIT:** It works fine, if you call super which is commented out.

Comment: Not sure, but isn't it because __variablename is a special variable? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1301369/2537322

Comment: More curiously, why does it *work* if you call `super()`?

Comment: Not an answer, but adds more detail - if you change it from `__baz` to `baz` both calls print 21. If you call `super()` and leave as `__baz` they print `40` and `21` respectively.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1301346/748858

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The double underscore attributes have their *names mangled* based on the **current/containing** namespace.  In the function `foo`, the current namespace is `Foo` so when python looks up `self.__baz`, it will actually look for `self._Foo__baz` due to the name mangling scheme.  Since nowhere in `Foo` have you actually set an `__baz` attribute, the class has no `_Foo__baz` attribute (it has a `_Bar__baz` attribute since you set `self.__baz` in a method within `Bar`).

Of course, as you've probably noticed, if you call `Foo.__init__(self)` in `Baz.__init__` (directly or via `super`), you'll see the problem go away because `Foo.__init__` sets `__baz` (i.e. `_Foo__baz`).

Comment: so the foo method is not inherited correct? I am a little confused as to what is happening here...

Comment: @user1988876 -- the `foo` method *is* inherited.  But when you call it, the attribute that it is trying to access is *missing*.  When python sees `self.__baz` inside the definition of the `Bar` class, it changes it to `self._Bar__baz`.  When it sees `self.__baz` inside the definition of the `Foo` class, it changes it to `self._Foo__baz`.  The whole idea here is so that `self.__baz` inside `Foo` can be distinct from `self.__baz` inside `Bar`.

Comment: So actually when he does call `super(Bar, self).__init__()` child class Bar's object has **two** attributes one is `_Bar__baz` (because he do `self.__baz = 21` in child class init method) and other is `_Foo__baz` from parent class **?** Whereas in error case (if he doesn't call `super(Bar, self).__init__()`) Bar's object has only one attribute that is `_Bar__baz` **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan -- Exactly.

Comment: Thanks, Yesterday only I learned inheritance in Python I don't understand a word "*`current/containing namespace`*"  .. what does it mean.

Comment: It means that `Foo.__init__` is in the `Foo` namespace.  `Bar.__init__` is in the `Bar` namespace.  When python is creating a class, it creates a new namespace (effectively with the name of the class).  All of the functions and variables in that class belong to that namespace.  So, when you're in `Foo.__init__` the "current namespace" is `Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

When you name variables with double underscore like that in python the member name will be obfuscated. Declaring `__baz` gives you a member `_Bar__baz`.

```
class Bar(Foo):
 def __init__(self):
     #super(Bar, self).__init__()
     self.__baz = 21
 def bar(self):
     print self._Bar__baz

x = Bar()
x.bar()
>>> 21
```

Comment: you have changed the definition of function `bar`. I would like to know why it works when the super call is made, as I made in my edit

Comment: + as you added a trick that is helpful for me, but is it not bad practice to use `_Bar__baz` explicitly **?**

Answer (score 2):

By using the initial double underscores on `__baz` you requested "name mangling" to make a "private" variable.  It's documented here:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references

If you change the name from `__baz` to just `baz` your code will work as shown.

Answer (score 1):

Since python 3.6, we can now use the `__init_subclass__` function, which is called automatically before `__init__` of the Child.

```
class Foo(object):
     def __init_subclass__(self):
         self.__baz = 40
     def foo(self):
         print(self.__baz)

class Bar(Foo):
     def __init__(self):
         self.__baz = 21
     def bar(self):
         print(self.__baz)

x = Bar()
x.foo()
x.bar()
```

output

```
40
21
```